# Azure Media services - Assets shows error

Tags: azure-media-services

I am trying to see my list of assets in Azure media services in the Azure portal. But all I get is a text that says "AssetsListPartReference" and an image of a crying cloud. See the attached image. I was previous able to see the asset list but I have no idea what has gone wrong.

I would appreciate any help.[image]

Comment: Thanks for reaching out - we'd likely need more details like your Azure Subscription ID, Media Service account name and Data Center name. Could you possibly share those details offline with us via an e-mail to amshelp at Microsoft dot com?

Comment: @ Anil Murching I actually ended up deleting the media service. I had just started so it was not a big lost. I will send you an email with details if I see the problem again.